# PostgreSQL on AWS ECS: psycopg2.OperationalError invalid port number 5432

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm having a problem with database connection via psycopg2 on AWS ECS.
I have an App container and a DB container. Containers are linked.

The App has an entrypoint script that checks if the DB is up before starting an app server.

```
$ until psql -h "$DB_HOST" -U "$DB_USER" -c '' && >&2 echo "Postgres is up"; do
    >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
    sleep 1
done

> Is the server running on host "db" (172.17.0.3) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
> Postgres is up
```

This part works fine, but as soon as the app server starts and tries to connect to the DB I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: invalid port number: "tcp://172.17.0.3:5432"
```

I have no idea what could be the case. This works fine when running locally with Docker.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across the same problem with Ruby on Rails. I had pretty much the same database config and I too used two linked containers for app and database (not directly, but through the Gitlab CI; under the hood it creates containers and links them). My environment variables had different names though: `POSTGRES_HOST`, `POSTGRES_PORT`, etc. Yet, your solution of explicitly defining `POSTGRES_PORT` worked for me too! But I couldn't leave it like that, I wanted to figure out why that helped and what caused the problem in the first place. So here's what I found.

The error says: `invalid port number: "tcp://172.17.0.3:5432"`. At first it may seem like a valid port 5432, but actually it is the whole string `"tcp://172.17.0.3:5432"` that isn't a valid port number. Something passed this URI instead of a port number to PostgreSQL, that's what the error says. You connect via psycopg, I used pg gem, but both of them are wrappers around [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq.html) C library, a part of PostgreSQL. Let's take a look at it to see *how* we're getting this error. There is a file `fe-connect.c` which contains functions that parse connection options. And here's the [relevant code](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/interfaces/libpq/fe-connect.c;h=14d234372620371d7ec53b3cbed22d87374c3e1a;hb=2fbecb66c45eccb8922c371084ae4f0b3a72a86b#l2091) (from PostgreSQL 10, that's the version I used):

```c
/* Figure out the port number we're going to use. */
if (ch->port == NULL || ch->port[0] == '\0')
        thisport = DEF_PGPORT;
else
{
        thisport = atoi(ch->port);
        if (thisport < 1 || thisport > 65535)
        {
                appendPQExpBuffer(&conn->errorMessage,
                                  libpq_gettext("invalid port number: \"%s\"\n"),
                                  ch->port);
                goto keep_going;
        }
}
```

It says: if `ch->port` is `NULL` or an empty string it means no port was provided with connection options, then let's use `DEF_PGPORT`, the precompiled default port, usually 5432; and if `ch->port` is present, let's convert it to int with `atoi` and check if it's between 1 and 65535.

If `ch->port` is `"tcp://172.17.0.3:5432"`, `atoi(ch->port)` returns 0, it's less than 1, so that's how we get this error.

By the way, in recent PostgreSQL versions one would get a more informative error: `invalid integer value "tcp://172.17.0.3:5432" for keyword "port"`. That's because [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=e7a2217978d9cbb2149bfcb4ef1e45716cfcbefb;hp=0d45cd96fd0f3387d1bcf7e6f873c73c4f251df8) replaced the above `atoi` with a custom error-checking string conversion function.

Okay, this URI appears in place of a port number in libpq connection options. But how it gets there? Turns out, because of Docker.

Docker containers can have names, either auto generated or provided with `--name` option to the `run` command. When you use `--link` option to link two containers, you specify the other container's name and optionally an alias. By default the alias is the same as the name. Probably, your database container had a name/alias `db`, mine was named `postgres` (Gitlab by default names a container with its image name, in my case: [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)).

When you link containers, Docker [defines a bunch of environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#environment-variables), these variables are named based on container names/aliases. One of the variables is `<alias>_PORT`, it contains the URI of the container’s exposed port. Not just port number, but a complete URI (like the one you'd get from `docker port <alias>` command). Here's where you get `"tcp://172.17.0.3:5432"` from, it is written by Docker to the `DB_PORT` variable, because your database container happens to be named `db`.

After all, possible solutions are:

- redefine `DB_PORT` variable after Docker links the containers (as you did),
- rename `DB_PORT` variable in the config,
- set another alias for the db container.

Comment: You went very deep into this rabbit hole. Impressive! Thanks a lot for this explanation. Unfortunately I'm not able to check it within this project anymore.

Comment: I just ran into this exact same issue, with GitLab CI Services and overlapping environment variables. Those are some pretty unexpected side effects. Docker really shouldn't spam environment variables like that.

Answer (score 3):

So to give it a little more background. The app is written in Django and here is the database config section:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # Requests will be wrapped in a transaction automatically
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'postgres'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8'
        }
    }
}
```

The `psql` command from the entry script was connecting just fine, using the default `5432` port.

Now when the Django tried to open connection, it used the default value of `5432` from this `os.getenv('DB_PORT', 5432)` call, as I did not set the `DB_PORT` ENV explicitly, not seeing a reason to do so.

Being out of ideas I've set the `DB_PORT` ENV explicitly in AWS ECS Task definition and ... surprise, it worked! For whatever reason (maybe it was passed as `str` instead of `int` when set explicitly).

I confirmed it 2 times by adding / removing the ENV var definition from the task configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cmd="$@"
if [ -z "$POSTGRES_USER" ]; then
    export POSTGRES_USER=postgres
fi

export DATABASE_URL=postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_USER


function postgres_ready(){
python << END
import sys
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="$POSTGRES_USER", user="$POSTGRES_USER", password="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD", host="postgres")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)
END
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - continuing..."
exec $cmd
```